# How to pass list from Struts action class to Jsp dropdown

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, struts2

I am new to *Struts2*. This is just a example for my problem.I have two dropdown in my jsp page named Author and Books.When I select Author, other dropdown should populate the book list relevant to that author.

What I did here, I get selected author id and pass it into action class method using jQuery ajax. Using dao class methos I got the list of book names relevant to that id. Every thing is fine up to that.

Problem is how can I pass that list from action class to Book dropdown in jsp?

```js
function getBooks(){

var authorId = document.getElementById("authorId").value;

  $.ajax({ 
     method: "GET",
     url: "getBooks",
     data: { "authorId" : authorId},
     traditional: true,
     success:
         function()
         {
      console.log("Success");
         },
     error: 
     function()
         {
      console.log("Fail");
         }
 });
}
```

This is my Action class

```js
public class ProjectPostAction {
 private int authorId;

 public final int getAuthorId() {
  return authorId;
 }

 public final void setAuthorId(int authorId) {
  this.authorId = authorId;
 }

public String getBooks() throws DAOTransientException, DBConfigException{
  
  BookDao bookDao = new BookDao();
  List <Book> bookList = bookDao.getBooks(this.authorId);
  
  for(int i=0; i<bookList.size(); i++){
   System.out.println("Book Names " + bookList.get(i).getName());
  }

  return "success";  
 }
......................

}
```

Comment: Hope this refrance guide you https://coderanch.com/t/585636/framework/Dependable-dropdowns-jsp-struts

Comment: try also http://www.raistudies.com/struts-1/ajax-with-struts-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```js
public class ProjectPostAction {
 private int authorId;
 private InputStream inputStream;

 public final InputStream getInputStream() {
  return inputStream;
 }

 public final void setInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
  this.inputStream = inputStream;
 }


 public final int getAuthorId() {
  return authorId;
 }

 public final void setAuthorId(int authorId) {
  this.authorId = authorId;
 }


public String getBooks() throws DAOTransientException, DBConfigException{
  
  BookDao bookDao = new BookDao();
  List <Book> bookList = bookDao.getBooks(this.authorId);
  
  String bookListByAuthorId = "<select name="bookListByAuthorId">";

  for(int i=0; i<bookList.size(); i++){
            bookListByAuthorId += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + bookList.get(i).getName() + "</option>";
        }

  bookListByAuthorId += "</select>";
  inputStream = new StringBufferInputStream(bookListByAuthorId);

  return "success";  
 }
......................

}

/////////////////////////////////////////////

<action name="getBooks" class="#myActionClass" method="getBooks">
   <result name="success" type="stream">
   <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
            <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
         </result>
   <result name="failure">./failure.jsp</result>
   <result name="error">./error.jsp</result>
  </action>
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe can try to retrun to view?

**Action**

```
String bookListByAuthorId = "<select name="bookListByAuthorId">";

for(int i=0; i<bookList.size(); i++){
            bookListByAuthorId += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + bookList.get(i).getName() + "</option>";
        }

bookListByAuthorId += "</select>";
```

return bookListByAuthorId;

**AJAX**

```
    success:
        function(result)
        {
        $("body").append(result);
        },
```

Comment: How you configure struts.xml?